# Are there any advantages to using React with functions only?

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone enlighten on the advantages or disadvantages to using React in a purely functional manner vs the OO approach.
Are there performance gains to get or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: Did you do any research? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36097965/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59841274/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61859809/3001761, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe apparently not. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use functional components you can use the new react features like hooks and context API, but you can do the same thing with classes but without hooks!